# how can I find elements of a list that are not included in another haskell list

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell and wanted to make the set difference between two haskell lists. For instance, I have list `a` and `b` and want `a-b`, i.e. `[4,5,6,7]`.

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 
let b = [1,2,3]
```

Is there any built in function for doing this operation.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `(\\)` operator in `Data.List`, be warned that it only removes the first instances of each, so

```
> [1..7] \\ [1..3]
[4,5,6,7]
> [1,1,1] \\ [1,2]
[1,1]
```

If you want a true "set difference", use `Data.Set`:

```
> import qualified Data.Set as Set
> Set.fromList [1..7] Set.\\ Set.fromList [1..3]
> Set.fromList [1,1,1]
fromList [1]
> Set.fromList [1,1,1] Set.\\ Set.fromList [1,2]
fromList []
```